# Funções com async / await executando fora de ordem

Tags: javascript, async-await

Alguém consegue me explicar se é o comportamento esperado, ou se errei alguma coisa no código abaixo? O comportamento esperado (no meu entendimento) seria logar 1,2,3 em sequência.

```js
let funcao1 = async() => {
  console.log(1)
  await funcao2()
  console.log(3)
}

let funcao2 = async() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(2)
  }, 1000);
}

funcao1()
```

Comment: Faça sem o setTimeout pra ver, chamando o console.log diretamente que fica mais fácil entender. Isso não tem nada a ver com async, se fizer com chamada normal de função sincrona dá na mesma (vai sair da ordem por causa do timeout, que simplesmente "agenda" a chamada, fora do fluxo normal).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não, porque a `Promise` implicitamente retornada por `funcao2` é resolvida logo depois que a função é chamada (com um ínfimo delay devido ao modo como operações essas tarefas são empilhadas pelo JS).

Isso faz com que o `await` não aguarde que `2` seja imprimido no console, que só será feito após 1 segundo desde a chamada à função `setTimeout`.

Se você quiser fazer 1, 2 e 3 serem impressos em ordem, `funcao2` deve retornar uma `Promise` que aguarde o um segundo do `setTimeout`. Nesse caso, uma `Promise` terá que ser retornada explicitamente, o que torna a anotação `async` desnecessária em `funcao2`. Veja:

```js
async function funcao1() {
  console.log(1);
  await funcao2();
  console.log(3);
}

function funcao2() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(2);
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

funcao1();
```

Comment: Em resumo, faltou o `resolve()` que é o básico dos promises :D